# Access to the internet at a certain time even if the phone is asleep

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have to do something exactly at a certain time, even when the phone is sleeping. My task requires internet access.

I used to do that:
AlarmManager with WakefulBroadcastReceiver, then I startWakefulService class  extends IntentService.

Everything works perfectly while the phone (with Andoid Marshmallow) is active. After falling asleep, I don't have access to the Internet. 
Additional note: I don't need Wi-Fi, just 3G or something.

Comment: if you want to perform your task if the phone is asleep and do your work with internet then you should work with service not intent service and you can start your service with alarms or any other checks. it will help you working with background functionality.

Comment: I did as you suggested. Unfortunately the effect is the same. I call service every minute (just for test) and in AsyncTask I try to make a simple query to the database by Internet. It works but only in active mode. Maybe I missed something? How to force renewal of internet connection?

Comment: I am on the way to solve this problem. Who wants to know about Optimizing for Doze and App Standby [link](Https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) 
This was introduced in Android 6.0, it means that Network access is suspended in Doze mode !!!